# Redirect IIS Request from non-www to www (with multiple domains spanning across multiple TLDs)

Tags: redirect, iis

I have an ASP.NET MVC site running on Azure (IIS).

I would like to create a rewrite rule in the web.config (unless someone has a better idea) to redirect any request for a domain which does not have a subdomain to the same address that includes www.  This has to work across multiple domains, subdomains and TLDs.

For instance:

```
domain1.com                 -> www.domain.com
domain5.buzz                -> www.domain5.buzz
http://domain2.com          -> http://www.domain2.com
http://domain2.co.uk        -> http://www.domain2.co.uk
sudomain.domain5.buzz       -> sudomain.domain5.buzz
https://domain5.buzz        -> https://www.domain5.buzz
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0):

The only way that I can figure out to solve this is to statically type the accepted TLDs:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RedirectRoot">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)*)+(\.)(com|net|org|buzz|edu|gov|co.uk)(:[0-9]+)?$"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```